# JavaScript Как построить такой алгоритм?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо сделать три действия на веб странице.

Действие №1 - кликать по ссылке

Действие №2 - ожидать появления класса

Действие №3 - получить/составить список

Скрипт первого и третьего действия у меня есть (см.ниже), если их вставить в консоль поочерёдно, к примеру вставляем первый скрипт запускаем, после появления ссылок запускаем третий скрипт, то всё это работает.

Но мне нужно составить один полноценный скрипт, в котором будет происходить в первую очередь нажатие на ссылку, ожидание появления класса, только после этого вывод списка.

Чтобы реализовать ожидание мне скорее всего необходимо использовать `MutationObserver` или `DOMInserted (Listener)`, чтобы реализовать последовательность `Promise` или `Async/Await`. Но я не очень хорошо знаю эти темы

Помогите пожалуйста как правильно построить такой алгоритм?

Действие №1

```
document.querySelector('#dle-content > div.section > ul > li:nth-child(3)').click();
```

Действие №3

```
(function() {
    var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cdn_download_item span:first-child'));
    var linksArray = new Array();
    for (element of elements) {
        linksArray.push(element.innerText);
    }

    return linksArray;
})();
```

---

Решил все это через MutationObserver
Теперь необходимо обернуть все это в одну функцию которая будет возвращать массив linksArray, как это сделать?

```
var target = document.body;
const config = { 
    childList: true,
    attributes: true, 
    characterData: true, 
    subtree: true, 
    //attributeFilter: ["id"],
    attributeOldValue: true, 
    characterDataOldValue: true 
}

const callback = function(mutations)
{
    var linksArray = new Array();
    if(document.querySelector(".cdn_download_item"))
    {
    var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cdn_download_item span:first-child'));
    for (element of elements) {
        linksArray.push(element.innerText);
    }
    console.log(linksArray); //HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(target, config);
document.querySelector('#dle-content > div.section > ul > li:nth-child(3)').click();
```

Comment: Там запрос какой-то уходит по ссылке? Может через fetch проще получить необходимую информацию, если вы на этой странице находитесь?

Comment: Проблема не в получение информации, нужно всего лишь реализовать ожидание появления класса

Answer (score -1):

Создайте свою коллекцию, которая будет вас уведомлять о заполнении.

Кроме этого, классы в элементы добавляются методами `element.classList.add` или `element.classList.toggle`, их можно можно модифицировать таким образом, чтобы они после добавления класса, записывали элемент в вашу коллекцию.

см. комментарии по коду ниже.

```js
const link = document.querySelector('.link')
const listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list__item'))

//ваша коллекция, принимает максимальную длину и колбек на завершение
class MyCollection {
  constructor(maxLength, onComplete){
    this.maxLength = maxLength
    this.collection = []
    this.complete = onComplete
  }
  
  add(item){
    this.collection.push(item)
    if (this.collection.length == this.maxLength){
      this.complete()
      console.log('Печать коллекции')
      console.log(this.collection)
    }
  }
}


//ваш коллбек на завершение
const doSomethingOnComplite = () => {
  //ваши действия
  console.log('Всё добавлено')
}

//создаем коллекцию передаем длину вашего исходного списка элементов и коллбек на завершение
const myItems = new MyCollection(listItems.length, doSomethingOnComplite)


//заглушка на фетч
let fetchTimeout = () => {
  console.log('start request')
  
  return new Promise(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('get response')
      listItems.forEach((item)=>{
        item.classList.add('added-class')
      })
    }, 2000);
  });
}

//обработчик нажатия на ссылку
link.onclick = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetchTimeout()
}

//модифицируем добавление класса 
listItems.forEach((item)=>{
  //сохраняем стандартный обработчик
  item.classList.defaultAdd = item.classList.add
  
  //модифицируем
  item.classList.add = (...args) => {
    //выполняем стандартное добавление класса
    item.classList.defaultAdd(...args)
    myItems.add(item)
  }
})
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#">link</a>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">1</li>
  <li class="list__item">2</li>
  <li class="list__item">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я добавил дополнения пожалуйста прочитайте его